# GROUP BY case statment

Tags: sql

See, i got some `CASE` statament within my query. I want to use that custom `CASE` field in my `GROUP` clause.
If you look at `screenshoot` you see that `Bottle Type` appears twice for same `Driver name` due `Bottle Type` is not under `GROUP` clause. How caxn i group on that?

```
SELECT ur.UserId, ur.Name AS 'Driver name', CASE
    WHEN bt.isFilled = 1 THEN bt.Name + ' filled'
    WHEN bt.isFilled = 0 THEN bt.Name + ' not filled'
END AS 'Bottle Type', SUM(wi.Amount) As 'Amount'
FROM T_Order As w
    INNER JOIN T_OrderItem As wi ON w.OrderId = wi.FK_OrderID
    INNER JOIN T_Users As ur ON w.FK_ActionReceiverID = ur.UserId
    INNER JOIN T_BottleT As bt ON wi.FK_BootleTID = bt.BottleTId
    GROUP BY ur.UserId, ur.Name, w.ADate, bt.Name, bt.isFilled
    ORDER BY  ur.Name, w.ADate ASC;
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You can put the whole case *expression* within your group by clause if needs be, however, I don't think that is the issue. My guess would be that there are two different values for `ADate` within that for George_Kierbut, and since you are grouping by `ADate` you are getting two rows. You are only using `ADate` to sort, so does this need to be in the group by, could you sort by the min or max of this (e.g `ORDER BY MIN(w.ADate) DESC`)

Comment: @GarethD that's true therefore i removed ADate from GROUP BY and from ORDER + i did as Gordon sugested and it works !

Comment: If you remove `ADate` from the group by you shouldn't actually need to include the case expression. You can keep your code a bit cleaner and simply group by `ur.UserId, ur.Name, bt.Name, bt.isFilled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeat the expression in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ur.UserId, ur.Name AS Driver_name,
       (CASE WHEN bt.isFilled = 1 THEN bt.Name + ' filled'
             WHEN bt.isFilled = 0 THEN bt.Name + ' not filled'
        END) AS Bottle_Type, SUM(wi.Amount) As Amount
FROM . . . 
GROUP BY ur.UserId, ur.Name,
         (CASE WHEN bt.isFilled = 1 THEN bt.Name + ' filled'
               WHEN bt.isFilled = 0 THEN bt.Name + ' not filled'
          END)
```

You haven't mentioned the database.  Some allow you to use column aliases in the `GROUP BY`.

Also, I removed the single quotes from the column names.  *Only use single quotes for string and date constants!*  Whatever database you have has escape characters for identifiers -- square braces, double quotes, or backticks.  However, it is better to choose names that do not need to be escaped.

Comment: Also as sugested by @GarethD in comment had to be done

Comment: @Arie . . . A comment that appeared three minutes after this answer, I might point out.